# Extract value containing in a line from a text file using groovy

Tags: groovy, text-files

i want to extract a value of token in a line from a text file.

The line from the text file is:

```
<response>{"timestamp": "2013-11-12T14:55:43Z", "data": {"profile": null, "ticket": "f644231-6d46-44c7-add6-de3a4422871e", </response>
```

groovy file is:

```
    // read the file from path
    def file = new File('c:/tmp/response.txt')
    // for example read line by line
    def data= file.eachLine { line ->
        // check if the line contains your data 
        if(line.contains('"ticket":')){
            return line     
        }
    }
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('ticket',data)
```

So here it's not storing any value in my variable ticket.
Any help, please

Comment: Does the file have json text? if yes, you could use JsonSlurper

Comment: the file is xml containing a json format but i converted to txt file

Answer (score 9):

Replace

```
def data= file.eachLine { line ->
    // check if the line contains your data 
    if(line.contains('"ticket":')){
        return line     
    }
}
```

With

```
def data= file.filterLine { line ->
    line.contains('"ticket":')
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tim_yates, with your code, it displays all the line containing data

Comment: Finally, i found a solution with point and click function which generate itself the groovy for the node we are looking.