# How Groovy can find a specific data in a line from a text file?

Tags: groovy

i have a text with this data :

```
<item>
            <response>{"timestamp": "2014-11-14T15:53:35Z", "data": null, "success": false, "error": {"message": "Accounts @xxx.com are not recognized.", "code": 404, "label": "Not Found"}}</response>
</item>
```

I want to find only this:
"error": {"message": "Accounts @xxx.com are not recognized.", "code": 404, "label": "Not Found"}

And then create a text file with this data.

I tried this:

```
def line = null
new File("c://temp//file.txt").eachLine { currentLine, lineNumber ->
    if (lineNumber == 9) {
        line = currentLine
    }
}
log.info "Line 9 = $line"
```

With this groovy code, i display the line i want but i cannot find the specific data mentioned before.

Any help please
Thank you

Comment: why are you checking for line#9 in specific? Provide more details on "i cannot find the specific data mentioned before" . What do you see when you print? You need to extract the text from <response> tag and using JsonSlurper#parseText you can parse it into a Json object and fetch error field.

Comment: i need to extract this data the message inside this line <response>{"timestamp": "2014-11-14T15:53:35Z", "data": null, "success": false, "error": {"message": "Accounts @xxx.com are not recognized.", "code": 404, "label": "Not Found"}}</response>

Comment: This looks suspiciously like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679161/extract-value-containing-in-a-line-from-a-text-file-using-groovy/33679270#33679270

Comment: Thank you, i found a solution with a simple groovy code the get data from my text file, thank you