# How to base64 decode value of dynamic json array in NiFi?

Tags: json, base64, apache-nifi, decode, jolt

I want to base64 decode encoding string of json array property not using hard code!!

This array size is dynamic.

Is there the way of decoding value using JoltTransformJson in NiFi?

Input JSON

```json
{
  "A": [
       {
         "CC" : "Encoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       },
       {
         "CC" : "Encoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       }
     ]
  "B": "any string"
}
```

Output JSON

```json
{
  "A": [
       {
         "CC" : "Decoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       },
       {
         "CC" : "Decoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       }
     ]
  "B": "any string"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with NiFi you can use `UpdateRecord` processor for update a specific record,

this is the Official Guide - [NiFi Record Path Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#base64encode).

you need to add `base64Decode(/A.CC)` and this `base64Decode(/B)` to your processor.

I leave you the link for a guide with examples and screenshots -> [Example](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Update-the-Contents-of-FlowFile-by-using-UpdateRecord/ta-p/248267)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I applied this to my NiFi. But I have a error message of "base64Decode Function does not exist". I set the Replacement Value strategy to "Record Path Value". Do you know why it has error?

Comment: When I check my NiFi version and RecordPath Guid, there is no base64Decode function.... ㅜ.ㅜ Thanks...

Comment: But in my NiFi, Expression Language has base64Decode funtion. So is there any other way?

Comment: yes the solution is more complicated,
with `EvaluateJsonPath` you enter the json values ​​as attributes, and with `UpdateAttibutes` you apply the Base64 Decode and now you can use `UpdateRecord` with the new attribute or use `Jolt`

Comment: yes I understand your solution. But When I tried to use **EvaluateJsonPath** and **UpdateAttributes** before, I can change the value of only one property with array size 1, but when array size is dynamic and more, I can't apply this. The fix size is OK, but dynamic size is very difficult..... How can i get all elements of array in **EvaludateJsonPath** and **UpdateAttributes** ?

Comment: the only solution i have in mind is to use `groovy / python` scripts example this --> [groovy example ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679161/extract-value-containing-in-a-line-from-a-text-file-using-groovy)
, put the line on attribute and manipolate it

Comment: @Taewoo open a new question maybe I have a script that can be useful to you

Comment: Oh I also that is only solution! Thanks for your answer!
Here is new Question link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73296198/how-to-use-groovy-or-python-to-decode-dynamic-json-array-value-in-nifi