# How to use groovy or python to decode dynamic json array value in NiFi?

Tags: python, json, groovy, base64, apache-nifi

I want to decode base64 encoding string value of dynamic size array in NiFi json content.

I try to use **EvaluateJsonPath** and **UpdateAttributes**, but the array size is dynamic and I can't get all elements index variable like for loop.

And then I also try to use **UpdateRecord**. It is very perfect to me. However, in my NiFi version, It doesn't contain "base64Decode" function of NiFi Record Path......

So I want to try to use script processor.

How can i write groovy / python script using streaming data.

Here is example input and output JSON.

Input JSON :

```json
{
  "A": [
       {
         "CC" : "Encoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       },
       {
         "CC" : "Encoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       }
     ]
  "B": "any string"
}
```

Output JSON :

```json
{
  "A": [
       {
         "CC" : "Decoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       },
       {
         "CC" : "Decoded string",
         "DD" : "any string"
       }
     ]
  "B": "any string"
}
```

Comment: here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075411/how-to-convert-unix-time-to-timestamp-with-nifi/72077347#72077347 however i don't understand what do you mean by "base64 decoded string" because base64 decode returns array of bytes...

Comment: Oh thank you! Let me refer this! I mean this example. Base64Encode "John" -> "Sm9obg==" and Base64Decode "Sm9obg==" -> "John"

Comment: In groovy it'll be like `new String( encoded.decodeBase64(), "UTF-8" )`

Answer (score 2):

in NiFi you can use **ExecuteGroovyScript** with this code

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != null) {

    def inputFlow = flowFile.read().getText("UTF-8").readLines()
    
    def search = inputFlow.findAll { it.contains('"CC" :') }
    def searchStr = search.toString()
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'search', searchStr)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

now you have a attribute **search** with line of CC, or you can add base64 decoding to this code as well

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I solve my question refering their answer as following Groovy code.

I have to parse text because decoded string is also Json string.

If I don't parse decoded string, result is contains "\" char because it is just string, not Json string

Thanks All!

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput; 
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile == null) {
    return;
}

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->

    def content = inputStream.getText("UTF-8")

    def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)    

    data.A.each{obj ->

         def decodedString = new String(obj["CC"].decodeBase64())
         def decodedJsonObject = new JsonSlurper().parseText(decodedString)
         obj["CC"] = decodedJsonObject
    }
   
    outputStream.write(JsonOutput.toJson(data).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```